# MSTest can not find App_GlobalResources assembly

Tags: .net, asp.net, unit-testing, localization, mstest

Trying to unit test a web application using mstest I have that problem with resources included in App_GlobalResources folder in the web applications.

Those resources are built at runtime and because of that they are not found when running the unit tests.

How are you solving this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most acceptable solution I have found is to avoid using App_GlobalResources and configure resource building at compile time:

http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2009/07/16/resource-files-and-asp-net-mvc-projects.aspx